# Storing an image dataset into 4D array then showing each image leads to distorted colors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib

I am trying to store an image dataset into a 4D ndarray then plot each image as follows:

```
i=0
for j in imagelist:
  imageall[i] = misc.imread(j) ##(36, 570, 760, 3)
  plt.imshow(imageall[i])
  plt.show()
  i=i+1
```

However, showing the image from the 4D ndarray gives a bluish image whereas simply reading the image and plotting it shows the image in its normal coloring.

I have compared channels (visually and by computing means in the 2 cases and they are exactly the same).

Can anyone explain the reason for change in displayed image coloration when reading single image and when reading to a 4D ndarray?

[image: Result from showing single image]

[image: Result from showing the same image but from the 4D ndarray]

Comment: Can you show some screenshots?

Comment: I  added image screenshots to when showing the single image, and same image but from 4D array

Comment: Perhaps the dtype is different in the two cases and this makes the colormap being used in one case. What is `imageall`? Compare its dtype to what `imread` returns.

Comment: Yes!!! That was it, the single image was uint8 while the 4D ndarray was float64... Setting the ndarray dtype to uint8 fixed it.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: I'm glad I could help:) I realized that the problem is somewhat subtle and others with a similar problem might stumble on this question, so I decided to add a full answer.

Comment: There's another minor note I'd make that's unrelated to your problem so I don't want to edit with that: you can do `for i,j in enumerate(imagelist):` and then you don't have to initialize and manually increment `i` in the loop.

Comment: Great thanks again : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your images have the same channel values as you noted in the question, so the difference in the result suggests that your values are being interpreted differently by `plt.imshow`. There's some magic to how `plt.imshow` interprets images based on type, so the most likely reason is that your original array is initialized with the wrong `dtype`.

Assuming that your pre-allocation is just something like

```
import numpy as np
imageall = np.empty((n_img,width,height,3))
# or imageall = np.zeros((n_img,width,height,3))
```

the resulting array will automatically have double type, i.e. `dtype=np.float64`. When you *mutate* this array with each image, the input `dtype=np.uint8` (as returned from `plt.imread`) is converted to double, effectively doing

```
imageall[i] = misc.imread(j).astype(np.float64)
```

So your channel values ranging from `0` to `255` are stored as floats, which is then misinterpreted by `plt.imshow`.

You just need to pre-allocate with the right dtype:

```
imageall = np.empty((n_img,width,height,3),dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: spent the past 20 mins trying to find this! thanks!!

Comment: @snazziii thank you, I'm very glad to have helped! :)